# $\varepsilon$ Property of Supremum Doesn’t Hold for All Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let the set $S$ be $S = [0,2] \cup \{5\}$, the union of $[0,2]$ and $\{5\}$. This is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? It has a supremum, which is 5.

Although $4 < 5$, there is no member $x \in S$ such that $4 < x < 5$, contrary to an often quoted property of supremum. In other words, let $\varepsilon = 1$, so $\varepsilon>0$. However, there is no member $x \in S$ in the region $[5 - \varepsilon,5]$.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes: there **is** an $x\in S$ in the region $[5-\epsilon, 5]$, namely $x=5$. There is no $x\in S$ in the region $(5-\epsilon, 5)$, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Well done @ Noah.

Answer (score 6):

You say "There is no member $x$ of $S$ such that $4<x<5$." But the part $x<5$ should not be there. That is not part of the definition of supremum.

In order for $s$ to be the supremum of a set $S$, it must be the case that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $x\in S$ such that $s-\varepsilon<x$. But the condition $x<s$ is **not** required.

Comment: The part x < 5 is first valid because every member of S is less than the Supremum of S in this case. Second, your s - e < x is the same as my 5 - 1 = 4 < x. The addition x < 5 is implicit in the definition of a supremum of a set. The issue remains that there is no such x in S such that s - e < x, where s=5 and e=1.

Comment: @KwabenaGod "The addition $x<5$ is implicit in the definition of a supremum" No, it's not - it should be "$\le$," not "$<$." You're getting the definition wrong.

Comment: The part $x<5$ is **not** valid because every member of $S$ is **not** less than the supremum of $S$ in this case. This is because in this case, the supremum of $S$ is a member of $S$, and is not less than itself.

Comment: You are right @ user-1

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is a non empty subset of the real numbers which is bounded above, it has a supremum, say $\sigma$. The correct statement is that

> For every $\varepsilon >0$, there is an $x\in S$ such that $\sigma - \varepsilon < x \leq \sigma$

So in your case, you have $\sigma = 5$, and you chose $\varepsilon =1$. So in this case $x=5$, and there is no contradiction, because we only have a weak inequality in the theorem: $ x \leq \sigma$.

---

And in fact what your example shows is that we CANNOT replace the weak inequality for a strict one in $\sigma - \varepsilon < x \leq \sigma$